# Which npm script hook can be used to remove node module BEFORE npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to remove a local package prior to `npm install`. I was hoping to use an npm script hook to accomplish this, but the ones that appear to be viable do not work. `preinstall` does not work because it will not run before the package tree is calculated ([discussed here](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm%20issue%2010379&oq=npm%20issue%2010379&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.2531j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)), and `prepare` seems to run into the same issue.

Is there an npm hook that can be used prior to the tree being calculated?

**Edit**

Here is more detail on the actual problem. My local module is being shared among other independent modules (i.e. a server and client module will depend on the content of this shared module). This module is written in Typescript. I want the other modules that share it to always have the latest, compiled version of this module. But, I don't want other developers to have to remember to compile the Typescript or update the version whenever they change it (i.e. a newer version would be caught by the other modules during npm install). In a sense, I don't want humans to have to remember to do these things. One effort to reduce this chance for error was adding a Typescript compilation step to the local module's `preinstall` hook.

The best I have been able to come up with is using a npm script hook, such as `preinstall` or `prepare` to remove the module prior to `npm install`, however, as mentioned above, those techniques will not work. At present I'm using a standard npm script that now must be run prior to `npm install` to perform the needed remove operation, which is not ideal.

Comment: *Why* would you do this? Implicitly removing a separate module on installation of another would be very unexpected.

Comment: For my particular case the purpose is to ensure that the latest code from a local module is used. We are not versioning our module, and (to my knowledge) npm install will not update the module if the version number is the same. So the actions are like this: remove the module --> re-install it to ensure latest code is being used.

Comment: I'm curious, why no versioning? At the very *least* it seems like it would be hard to otherwise tell if an "upgrade" actually worked properly/completely or not.

Comment: The module is not something that will change that often and we don't want to rely on people to ensure they are updating the version. I take it you don't have an answer to this question?

Comment: I still don't understand the rationale, but this just seemed like (and still does) an XY problem to me.

Comment: @mscdex I didn't know what an XY problem was until now - glad you mentioned it. I updated the question. Hope that clarifies the problem a little more.